# splitting a 6 digit integer in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an 6digit integer, let's say "153060" that I'll like to split into

int a = 15 (first 2 digits),

int b = 30 (second 2 digits),

int c = 60 (third 2 digits),

The first thing that comes to mind is to convert the int to a string, split it using SubString (or a variation), and then convert back to an int.

This seems like a highly inefficient way to do it though. Can anyone recommend a better/faster way to tackle this?

Thanks!

**Additional Info:** the reason for splitting the int is because the 6-digit integer represents HHMMSS, and I'd like to use it to create a new DateTime instance:

DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime (Year, Month, Day, a , b, c);

However, the user-field can only accept integers.

Comment: Why is a time being stored using base-10 representation in the first place, if it's not a string?

Comment: Premature optimization, the root of all evil.

Comment: You should only worry about efficiency if this going to be part of a bulk process. e.g. occurring thousands of times a second. Otherwise your described algorithm is fine. (Try to avoid premature optimization though in this case the algorithm is/should be localized. )

Comment: You could also try `DateTime.ParseExact(number.ToString(), "HHmmss")` so you wouldn't need `SubString()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
int i = 153060;

int a = i / 10000;
int b = (i - (a * 10000)) / 100;
int c = (i - ((a * 10000) + (b * 100)));
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding modulus, which is fairly costly compared to subtraction

Comment: @Cameron: If you're going to optimize at that level (which is *very* unlikely to be useful), you should remove the divisions altogether.

Comment: @Joren: Hah, yes, good point (though I don't see a way to remove the divisions in this particular case). If for some strange reason ultimate micro-optimization really is needed, it would be undoubtedly faster to have the input partitioned on bits in the first place, so only shifts and masks would be needed.

Comment: @Cameron: A division by a known constant can be replaced by a combination of additions, shifts and multiplications. I'm not sure how far the JIT goes with this, but I know an optimizing C++ compiler will do some crazy stuff. As a pseudocode example, uint64 y = x; y *= 0x11111111; y += x >> 3; y >>= 34; return (uint32)y; will return x / 60 if x is also an unsigned 32 bit integer.

Comment: @Cameron: Anyway, my point is, I would just write the modulus, since that is what represents what I'm trying to accomplish most obviously. If that turns out not to be fast enough, only then I would consider doing it a less obvious way.

Answer (score 21):

```
int y = number / 10000;
int m = (number - y*10000) / 100;
in d = number % 100;
```

Comment: You would need `int m = (number - (y * 10000)) / 100;` Edit: caught it before I could point it out!

Answer (score 18):

If your end goal is a `DateTime`, you could use [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370.aspx) to extract a `TimeSpan` from the string, then add it to a `DateTime`:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2011, 11, 2);
myDateTime = myDateTime.Add(time);
```

(Assumes >= .NET 4)

Comment: Yep, but only in .net 4 it appears.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm getting error message "System.TimeSpan does not contain a definition for 'ParseExact'.

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it :)

Comment: Yep. You could do something with `DateTime.ParseExact` but it probably wouldn't be as elegant as using `TimeSpan` :(

Answer (score 6):

You can do that without converting to string with:

```
int a = 153060 / 10000;
int b = (153060 / 100) % 100;
int c = 153060 % 100;
```

I am not sure about how efficient that is compared to converting to string. I think this is only 4 operations. So it might be faster.